# Problemas con JavaScript para mostrar los valores de un objeto

Tags: javascript, html, json

En el siguiente ejemplo podrás encontrar un Json con información previamente establecida. el problema es que los identificadores son numéricos.   ¿Como puedo extraer la informacion textual?

Ejemplo `Hola mundo`.

```js
var col =  [];
var mydata = 
[{
  "01:23:2018, 10:02:32" : "Hola",
  "01:23:2018, 10:02:38" : "Mundo",
  "01:23:2018, 10:02:40" : "Somo tu y yo",
   "username" : "Juan"
        },];   
                
                 
                 
             for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
                      for (var key in mydata[i]) {
                          col.push(key);
                            }
                            }
                            
                        console.log(col)
```

Comment: He intentando console.log(mydata.username) y me arroja el nombre Juan el problema es como colocar el identificador numerico.

Comment: Agrega una breve descripción de lo que has buscado, investigado e intentado. Referencia [ask].

Comment: He intentado insertar el texto en una variable ejemplo var z = ' "01:23:2018, 10:02:32" ' con doble comillas

Comment: ¿Y eso que tiene que ver con armar una tabla en HTML? :)

Comment: ¿conoces las etiquetas HTML `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`?

Comment: La idea es sacar los datos que contienen dichos JSON para poder armar una tabla dinámica en HTML. Pero primero debo tener la informacion.

Comment: Dime como harías para obtener un Hola Mundo con esta informacion que te he dado en el código.

Comment: Lo siento pero en este momento la pregunta no me parece ni buena ni  interesante tal cual está. Si la mejoras tal vez me anime.

Comment: Modifiqué la pregunta... espero me puedas ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mydata es un array que tiene como primer y único miembro un objeto con varias propiedades. Para extraer un dato puntual, es decir el valor de una propiedad, entre otras alternativas, se puede usar una doble "llave" de la siguiente forma:

```
mydata[0]["01:23:2018, 10:02:32"]
```

El siguiente ejemplo imprime a la consola el valor del enunciado anterior:

```js
var col = [];
var mydata = [{
  "01:23:2018, 10:02:32": "Hola",
  "01:23:2018, 10:02:38": "Mundo",
  "01:23:2018, 10:02:40": "Somo tu y yo",
  "username": "Juan"
}, ];

console.info(mydata[0]["01:23:2018, 10:02:32"])
```

Para imprimir todos los valores, una forma de adaptar el código de la pregunta es la siguiente:

```js
var col = [];
var mydata = [{
  "01:23:2018, 10:02:32": "Hola",
  "01:23:2018, 10:02:38": "Mundo",
  "01:23:2018, 10:02:40": "Somo tu y yo",
  "username": "Juan"
}, ];



for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
  for (var key in mydata[i]) {
    //col.push(key);
    console.info(mydata[0][key])
  }
}
```

---

Referencias

- [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON)
- [Indexed collections](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta me ha sido de utilidad. mi error fue colocar un punto entre la id y el objeto como lo muestro a continuación  console.info(mydata[0].[key]) un saludo.

Comment: Buena aclaración

Comment: @Mariano: Si, sí, rizando el rizo e primer elemento de un array puede ser un primitivo o un objeto y pues no es lo mismo una cadena JSON que un objeto JSON.

Comment: @Mariano de hecho si existe, es uno de los "built-in objects" de JavaScript (JSON.parse(...), JSON.stringify(...)) :) (no tengo objeciones en editar mi comentario anterior, pero ya pasó el tiempo para hacerlo)

Comment: @Mariano esta discusión amerita unos tequilas ;)

Comment: @Mariano  Me tardé pero ya entendí (creo) y edité la respuesta.